# Haskell Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation

Tags: haskell

```
getPage :: MVar String -> IO String
getPage m = do
  url <- takeMVar m
  putStrLn $ url ++ " is downloaded!"
  return url

testDownload :: IO ()
testDownload = do
  m <- newMVar "url1"
  pages <- replicateConcurrently 10 (getPage m)
  sequence_ [putMVar m ("url" ++ show i) | i <- [2..11]]
```

I'm just getting into concurrent programming in Haskell and still can't find my way around it. In the above code, the idea is to keep putting stuff into the `MVar String` while the threads created by `replicateConcurrently` will keep taking the MVars.

But I got a `***Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do, but the code doesn't actually do what you want.  In particular, it's the line

```hs
  pages <- replicateConcurrently 10 (getPage m)
```

that's causing you trouble.  It's true that you're creating 10 threads to run 10 different calls to `getPage m`, but then you're collecting the results, and because you're doing this "concurrently", you're waiting for all of the threads you created to finish before continuing.

The simplest way to achieve what you're doing is probably to use `mapConcurrently` instead of `replicateConcurrently` and not use the `MVar` at all, as in:

```hs
getPage :: String -> IO String
getPage url = do
  putStrLn $ url ++ " is downloaded!"
  return url

testDownload :: IO ()
testDownload = do
  pages <- mapConcurrently getPage ["url" ++ show i | i <- [2..11]]
  putStrLn $ unlines pages
```

---

However, there is a way to achieve your goal *and* use the `MVar` for communication.  The trick is that you need something like `replicateConcurrently` but that works *asynchronously*.  Consider, for instance:

```hs
replicateAsync :: Int -> IO a -> (IO [a] -> IO b) -> IO b
replicateAsync n a f = go n []
  where
    go n waits
      | n <= 0 = f $ sequenceA $ reverse waits
      | otherwise = withAsync a $ \w -> go (n-1) (wait w:waits)
```

The type signature is a cross between `withAsync` and `replicateConcurrently`, and the behavior is too.  The first argument is the number of threads to spawn, the second is the action to replicate, and the third is a continuation for what to do with the result.

You can use this to write `testDownload` close to what you had:

```hs
testDownload :: IO ()
testDownload = do
  m <- newMVar "url1"
  replicateAsync 10 (getPage m) $ \awaitPages -> do
    sequence_ [putMVar m ("url" ++ show i) | i <- [2..11]]
    pages <- awaitPages
    putStrLn $ unlines pages
```

Notice that unlike with `replicateConcurrently`, the result you're waiting for is *not* produced right away when you call `replicateAsync`.  Instead, in your continuation, you're given a value of type `IO [a]` (which I called `awaitPages` here).  When you perform this action, you'll actually do the synchronization and collection step, so as long as you do that *after* you sequence your `putMVar`s, then all the threads will be properly active at once.

Comment: I see. Well I've put the code `sequence_ [putMVar m ("url" ++ show i) | i <- [2..11]]` in a forkIO thread and it worked. Actually the original idea is to have a thread that's in charge of distributing the urls. Once it's empty, it will call some function to reload